# Как всем li в которых имеется ul задать .addClass('parrent')

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="menu">
<li"><a href="#">Heading1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Some text1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
<li><a href="#">JQuery</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Some text2</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
<li><a href="#">JQuery</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Some text</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: @Yura Ivanov парень видимо убежал радоваться

Comment: Минус за отвратительно оформленный вопрос и за ошибку в слове «parrent».

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, типичный новичек, который зарегистрировался, чтобы задать один единственный нубский вопрос и 1) либо больше никогда не посещать ресурс, 2) либо будет задавать еще кучу таких же элементарнейших вопросов, забывая отмечать верный.

Comment: @artuska уважение должно быть обоюдным. не думаю, что данный форум предназначен только для вопросов о "высших сферах", да и вопрос не особо очевидный, а пользоваться markdown'ом вы и сами научились не с первого раза. удержать новичка на форуме, наставив ему за первый же вопрос минусов, будет довольно сложно.

Comment: Ерунда, научился сразу же. А удерживать нубов не нужно — они ничего не вносят в сообщество, только получают, решая свои нубские вопросы.

Comment: @artuska, ах, какая честь видеть человека, который миновал стадию "нуба" и сразу стал профи.

Comment: @artuska что принесли вы, кроме нагатива и более половины ваших ответов с минусами? вот "умников" точно удерживать никто не стал бы...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, я принес правильные работающие ответы на вопросы и проблемы, для чего, собстенно, этот ресурс и задуман. А всякие «умники» ходят по всем ответам и ставят минуса просто так (это сейчвс только половина ответов заминусована, раньше прошлись по всем и все были в минусах).

Comment: @Deonis, естественно, у меня же есть глаза, которыми я вижу кнопку «отформатировать код». При чем тут стадия нуба или профи, тут дело в глазах и чувстве прекрасного, только и всего.

Comment: кто нибудь из модеров закройте вопрос, походу автор не соображает, что это нужно сделать.

Answer (score 11):

```
$('li:has("ul")').addClass('parent');
```

Comment: большое спасибо!   ...работает))

Comment: Это ответ на 10 голосов?Вы совсем потеряли вкус ответа?Я Вас не прызывають минусовать этот ответ просто я совсем потресен.

Comment: @SverxnovA, вы на ник отвечающего обратили внимание? )) Видать, поэтому так и прёт ;)

Comment: Deonis раскрыл тайну.